# How to set google drive file permissions in typescript with API v3?

Tags: typescript, google-drive-api

The docs for Google Drive API:s v2 -> `permissions` -> `insert` can be found here;
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert

The page has a javascript example at the bottom page where a `body` variable is assigned to the `resource` property of the object passed to the `insert` function.

I want to use the v3 version, because I'm writing typescript and the v3 version has a @types package;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi.client.drive,
type definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gapi.client.drive/index.d.ts

In v3 `insert` has been renamed to `create` and is documented here;
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

However, this doc page has no javascript example, and in the types package the object to pass to the create function has no `resource` property.

How am I supposed to migrate this part of the v2 code sample when using v3 from typescript?

```
  var body = {
    'value': value,
    'type': type,
    'role': role
  };
```

Comment: my 2c, don't use the JS library. It doesn't deal with many of the problems you will face, and is closed source, which means your app is depending on code that can,and does, frequently change.

Comment: So what should I use instead?

Comment: Just call the endpoints directly using fetch, XMLHttprequest or axios. You will find your life instantly simpler. I ended up writing my own wrapper to XmlHttprequest to deal with 501, 403, access token, etc after the 2nd time that Google introduced a bug to their closed library.